# d3js, what does it mean when the 2nd param in .data() is a function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried the following code:

```
var data = [
  {name: "Locke", number: 4},
  {name: "Reyes", number: 8},
  {name: "Ford", number: 15},
  {name: "Jarrah", number: 16},
  {name: "Shephard", number: 31},
  {name: "Kwon", number: 34}
];

d3.selectAll("div")
  .data(data, function(d) { return d ? d.name : this.id; })
                           // it should return a value, right? Where is the return value stored? Why doing this? 
     .enter()
     .append('h4')
    .text(function(d) { return d.number; });
```

I don't understand what does this line of code do:

```
.data(data, function(d) { return d ? d.name : this.id; })
```

The callback function should be executed against each item in data array, but then what? Why they want to do it? where is the return value stored?

Here is the appended element looks like, still no returned value. Here is the [official document for data() function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data). Can't find explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data) for the second argument in `data` function begins with the given document:

```
<div id="Ford"></div>
<div id="Jarrah"></div>
<div id="Kwon"></div>
<div id="Locke"></div>
<div id="Reyes"></div>
<div id="Shephard"></div>
```

Now, to this existing HTML structure you want to apply your data:

```
var data = [
  {name: "Locke", number: 4},
  {name: "Reyes", number: 8},
  {name: "Ford", number: 15},
  {name: "Jarrah", number: 16},
  {name: "Shephard", number: 31},
  {name: "Kwon", number: 34}
];
```

So you begin with a selection:

```
d3.selectAll("div")
```

The selection will return a list of HTML elements that already exist in the document. What the code in the documentation does is: insert `number`s from your data to the corresponding `div`s by matching `name`s from your data to `id`s of the elements, e.g. `<div id="Ford">15</div>`.

However, d3 doesn't know how to match those. If you don't specify the second argument, it will try to join data with your elements **by index** (first entry in data goes into first element, second into second, etc.). So, you'll get:

```
<div id="Ford">4</div>
<div id="Jarrah">8</div>
<div id="Kwon">15</div>
...
```

But, if you provide the second argument, which is called a *key function*, you can tell d3 where you want those numbers inserted.

> **A key function may be specified to control which datum is assigned to which element, replacing the default join-by-index**. This key function is evaluated for each selected element, in order, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM element. The key function is then also evaluated for each new datum in data, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the group’s new data, with this as the group’s parent DOM element. The datum for a given key is assigned to the element with the matching key.

```
// d is the current datum (the __data__ object on element, if any)
function(d) {
  // for every element let's see if there is a __data__ object;
  // existing elements that haven't been handled by d3 yet don't have it:
  return d ?
    d.name : // use `name` property from `data`
    this.id; // use element's id, same as this.getAttribute('id')
}
```

Now, using the above function as *key function* your HTML will look like:

```
<div id="Ford">15</div>
<div id="Jarrah">16</div>
<div id="Kwon">34</div>
<div id="Locke">4</div>
<div id="Reyes">8</div>
<div id="Shephard">31</div>
```

You can play around with it in this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mcu4uob7/)**. I've added a `console` call to the key function. Notice that it's called 12 times (6 for each element, then 6 for each datum (entry) in your data). The first 6 log `undefined` because there's no `__data__` on those elements yet.

The return value is not stored anywhere. It is used once to match an element to a datum, and then is discarded.

Comment: "function(d) { return d ? d.name : this.id; }" return a value, but the data is an object(e.g.: {name: "Locke", number: 4}), how does d3 know which key in the object to compare against the value returned by the key function?

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu *"how does d3 know which key in the object to compare"* – d3 will execute the key function for every element and every item in you data and will use the returned value (either `d.name` or `this.id`) for comparison. For example, a key `name` ("Locke", "Reyes", ...) in your object will be compared to element's `id` ("Ford", "Jarrah", ...).

Comment: @NicholaS.Xu, the data will be an object regardless the presence of the key function. The key function doesn't change the underlying data. To better understand the bounded data, check this documentation example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/d3.js/876/introduction-to-d3-js/17659/what-is-d3-data-driven-documents#t=201608070835401319321